# EditText printing $ when 4 is pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText where I only allow the characters $0123456789.

Everything is working well except when I press the number 4 (on virtual or hardware keyboard) it prints a dollar sign ($).

Why is it doing this?

Here is the XML for my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amount_text"
    style="@style/textbox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:digits="$0123456789."
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/amount_hint"
    android:inputType="textPhonetic|numberDecimal" />
```

Secondary question:

```
mAmountTxt.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
```

This achieves what I want (sans $).  However, it changes the virtual keyboard to one I don't want.  I want the phone keyboard with the big number buttons.

Comment: If you defined the edittextview as textPhonetic|numberDecimal, how do you even get the $ in the keyboard to be entered ?

Comment: Ok, i've removed that line and it works as expected. It allows to entere $ . and all the numbers correctly. I'm on a Stock 4.2 Galaxy Nexus

Comment: I couldn't tell you for sure.  It does let me define "$" as a valid digit in the `android:digits` tag.

Comment: Also, this problem with the 4 becoming a $ was happening on my emulator which was running 2.1.  My Android phone is running 4.1.2 and it does not have the problem.

Comment: What happens when you chuck out the "$" in android:digits="$0123456789? It's curious that $ is a shifted 4. Hmm

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm 100% sure that it doesn't relate directly to your EditText xml. I have tried your xml in Emu 2.1, Emu 4.0, Emu 4.1 and Real Phone 4.0, and it worked well in each.

Other possible causes:

- It might be the emulator - they are sometimes buggy. Can you try to make a new instance of the emulator and test it? Or, try restarting adb?
- It might be something programmatic. Do you do any replacing or something like that?
- I'm not sure what this does: `style="@style/textbox"`

---

Second, to make keyboard layout look like a phone, use this instead of setKeyListener

```
mAmountTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
I want the phone keyboard with the big number buttons.
```

Set `inputType` to:

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

instead of:

```
 android:inputType="textPhonetic|numberDecimal"
```